# Mageno : PHP Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in MAGENTODIR/shell/abstract.php on line 79

Tags: shell, magento-1.7, reindex

I normally do the reindexing of "catalog_url" by entering into "shell" directory through SSH & using "indexer.php" But suddenly yesterday I tried to implement the process but getting error. Simply the following command

```
php -f indexer.php info
```

is showing the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage' not found in MAGENTODIR/shell/abstract.php on line 79
```

I have changed the "Use flat catalog category" & "Use flat catalog product" to "No" and disabled the "Mage_Log" module output before trying yesterday's reindexing, as far as I can remember. Its Magento 1.7

Any idea or help would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: @ferozakbar the part of the "abstract.php" file that asking "Mage.php" for the Mage class has the following lines: http://pastebin.com/3TKGNkx7 Here line 5 of this snippet is the line 79 of the full "abstract.php" file

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. It was actually occurred because of APC. For testing, I disabled the APC by editing the ini here:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/apc.ini
```

by doing ";"

```
;extension=apc.so
```

Then tried the indexer from inside the magento shell

`php -f indexer.php info`

and everything worked properly.

Comment: This is a cause, not a solution. After re-enabling APC, what did you do to permanently fix the problem?